# How to prevent Angular from cuttin off url paramters after a question mark?

Tags: angular, parameters, router

given a url like http://www.example.com?a=?&b=2
Angular cuts the url off at the second question mark although a question mark is allowed in there according to the RFC definition.

Unfortunately I don't have the possibility to url encode the question mark or change the url in any other way.

Do you guys know how to change that behavior and keep the whole url?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Kinds regards,
Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'll look at the `Router` constructor in the [docs](https://angular.io/api/router/Router), it injects the `UrlSerializer`, which is later used to serialize / deserialize the routes. By default, Angular injects the `DefaultUrlSerializer`, which encodes the queryParams.

But you can inject your own implementation by specifying it in the providers of your module:

```
providers: [{ provide: UrlSerializer, useClass: YourCustomUrlSerializer }],
```

Of course you'll have to provide that custom implementation yourself. The interface is [quite simple](https://angular.io/api/router/UrlSerializer), so it'll look something like this:

```
export class YourCustomUrlSerializer implements UrlSerializer {
    parse(url: any): UrlTree {
        // Your implementation here
    }

    serialize(tree: UrlTree): any {
        // Your implementation here
    }
}
```

Sadly the logic is quite complex, so it's not as easy as writing few lines of code. You can check the default implementation [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/router/src/url_tree.ts) and build upon it.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks a million!
Greetings from Berlin